# How to extract unique elements from a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

Can someone suggest a way to extract unique elements from a data.frame?

I have noticed `unique`, but since it works on either rows or columns, it doesn't do what I'm looking for. I'm after unique cells from a data.frame.

e.g.,

```
df<-data.frame(V1=c("Hello","fat","man"),V2=c("cat","fat","Hello"),V3=c("man","dog","black"))
```

Extracting unique elements should give me  `c("Hello","fat","man","cat","dog","black")`

Comment: `as.character(unique(unlist(df)))`

Comment: Seems to work for me! Thanks.
If you post that as an answer I will add it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A 'data.frame' can be considered as a 'list' with columns as 'list' elements having the same length.  By using `unlist`, we can convert it to `vector` and then get the `unique` values and convert to 'character' class with `as.character`.

```
as.character(unique(unlist(df)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Or simply:

```
unique(as.vector(as.matrix(df)))
## [1] "Hello" "fat"   "man"   "cat"   "dog"   "black"
```